# Visual studio 2017 auto indentation problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual studio 2017 with Unity.
The problem is that the automatic indentation always moves the autocompleted code + any comments above it to the same level as the function. What I want is to either move it one level to the right or just stop autoindenting at all.
I have tried turning on and off all options (as far as I know) related to reformating / indentation and prettifying of the code without any result.

[image: Example here]

Comment: Hi and Welcome on StackOverflow. Do you mind posting a picture? And, by the way, are you using any third party tool/extension like ReSharper or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Under `Tools` → `Options` → `TextEditor` → `C#` → `CodeStyle` → `Formatting` → `Indentation` you have to **enable** the option `Indent block contents`

[image]